# get percentile for a score using apache math

Tags: java, math, statistics, percentile

I am using [Apache Math DescriptiveStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) to do some calculations on an `ArrayList<double>` called `scores`.  One of the values in `scores` is in a separate `double` value called `myScore`.  How do I use Apache Math to find the percentile score for `myScore`?

Here is my first attempt, but it is so cumbersome that there has to be an easier way:

```
int percentile = 0;
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();
double[] values = getValues(scores, minval, maxval);
// Add the data from the array
for( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    stats.addValue(values[i]);
}
for(int j=0; j<101; j++){
    if(stats.getPercentile(j)>myScore && stats.getPercentile<myScore){
        percentile = j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the dedicated method to solve your problem, but it can be solved in two steps using `Arrays.binarySearch`:

```
int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(stats.getSortedValues(), myScore);
double percentile = (pos < 0 ? -1 - pos : pos) * 100.0 / stats.getN();
```

It should be more efficient than your current solution.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for a correct answer.  I did, however, have to add rounding to your code to avoid printing an excess number of digits..